# jQuery burger menu works but with no animation. Only 'jumps' open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a burger menu which appears by the second media query, when the screen size gets to around 600px, it looks just as I want and works well but I can not get it to animate the 'slide' - when clicking the burger icon the menu just jumps out, as opposed to a nice slide, which is originally what the code was supposed to do. Any help? I'm sure I'm missing something small that I can't see.

```
<div id="burgermenu">
        <img src="images/burger-icon.png" id="button" width="50px" style="display: block; float: right;">
    </div>

    <div id="burgermenuclose">
        <img src="images/burger-icon-close.png" id="buttonclose" width="50px" style="display: block; float: left;">
        <div id="navigationContainer">
            <a href="index.html"><p id="mobile-navigation-title">Home</p></a>

            <a href="#"><p id="mobile-navigation-title">About</p></a>
            <a href="about.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Staff</p></a>
            <a href="faq.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">What we do</p></a>

            <a href="#"><p id="mobile-navigation-title">Research</p></a>
            <a href="team.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Global health</p></a>
            <a href="news.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Population change</p></a>
            <a href="contact.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Low fertility</p></a>
            <a href="about.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Female international migration</p></a>
            <a href="faq.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Demandside financing</p></a>

            <a href="#"><p id="mobile-navigation-title">Post graduate training</p></a>
            <a href="team.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">PhD</p></a>
            <a href="news.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Masters</p></a>
            <a href="contact.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Short courses</p></a>

            <a href="#"><p id="mobile-navigation-title">News</p></a>
            <a href="team.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Seminars</p></a>
            <a href="news.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Jobs &amp; bursaries</p></a>

            <a href="#"><p id="mobile-navigation-title">Projects</p></a>
            <a href="contact.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">MRC Global maternity &amp; child health</p></a>
            <a href="about.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">Newton institutional link award</p></a>
            <a href="faq.html"><p id="mobile-navigation">ESRC low fertility</p></a>

            <a href="team.html"><p id="mobile-navigation-title">Contact</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
 $("#burgermenuclose").hide();
 $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#burgermenuclose").animate({left: '250px;'});
    $("#burgermenuclose").show();
 });

 $("#menutext").click(function(){
    $("#aboutWrapper-mobile").animate({left: '250px'});
    $("#burgermenuclose").show();
 });

 $("#buttonclose").click(function(){
    $("#aboutWrapper-mobile").animate({left: '0px'});
    $("#burgermenuclose").hide();
 });

 $("#menutextclose").click(function(){
    $("#aboutWrapper-mobile").animate({left: '0px'});
    $("#burgermenuclose").hide();
 });
</script>
```

CSS

```
       #burgermenu{
       height: 70px;
       width: 40%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 10px;
       float: right;
       display: block;
      }

#burgermenuclose{
height: 100vh;
width: 50%;
background-color: #222e5b;
margin: 0 auto;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px darkgray;
top: 0;
overflow: scroll;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 200;
}

#menutext{
text-decoration: none;
color: #0e0e0e;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
display: block;
float: left;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 14px;
margin-left: -10px;
cursor: pointer;
}

#button{
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

#buttonclose{
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
}

#menutextclose{
text-decoration: none;
color: #0e0e0e;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
display: block;
float: left;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 14px;
margin-left: -10px;
cursor: pointer;
}

#navigationContainer{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
}

#mobile-navigation{
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
font-size: 18px;
color: #9a9a9a;
line-height: 3;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 30px;
font-weight: 100;
height: 60px;
transition: 0.2s;
margin: 0 !important; 
}

#mobile-navigation:hover{
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
font-size: 18px;
color: #ffffff;
line-height: 3;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
background-color: #dc9720;
height: 60px;
font-weight: 100;
}

#mobile-navigation-title{
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
font-size: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
line-height: 3;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
font-weight: 700;
height: 60px;
transition: 0.2s;
margin: 0 !important; 
}


<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do u have some js code there or it works on hover ?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: there's the javascript code under the HTML

Comment: here is a rough fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uy7yowL3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 250px isn't the correct value to get the output you want, but the reason it's not animating correctly is that you have as semi colon in the code below, after the 250px

```
 $("#burgermenuclose").hide();
 $("#button").click(function(){
     $("#burgermenuclose").animate({left: '250px;'});
     $("#burgermenuclose").show();
 });
```

Remove that semi-colon, and it appears to animate correctly

I might add, that you can actually move the div to the left by 250px by going

```
$("#burgermenuclose").hide();
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#burgermenuclose").animate({left: '+=250px'});
    $("#burgermenuclose").show();
});
```

The same works for `-=250px` as well.